# Can server-side access to Google Cloud Firestore be restricted for a service account to specific collections?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

According to my perusal of the Firestore documentation, it appears that granular permissions are only available for mobile/web clients, not for server-side clients (e.g. python google cloud libraries).

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview

Is this correct, or am I missing something?  If this is the case, are there any plans in place to allow restricting specific service accounts to specific collections within Firestore (similar to how permission to specific PubSub and Storage objects can be granted to specific SAs), without requiring an all-or-nothing project-wide permission model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Firestore doesn't have any per-service-account granular permissions.  Either the entire database is accessible, or it is not at all.

If you have questions about the future of Cloud Firestore, Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask.  Post those questions to the [official Cloud Firestore Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-firestore-discuss).